# Как изменить фон меню при прокрутке страницы (CSS)

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы при прокрутке страницы фон у меню вместе с лого становился чёрным?

```css
.logo {
  float: left;
  transition: all .3s ease 0s;
  color: black;
}
nav {
  float: right;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.navbar{
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar li a{
    color: white;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    transition: all .3s ease 0s;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.navbar li a:hover
{
  color: #32CD32;  
}
.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1100px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;

}
.navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="head">
        <div class="container">
            <img src="images/logo.png" lass="im1" >
            <nav class="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li class="home"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#courses">Courses</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#testomonial">Testomonial</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#faqs">Faqs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

Comment: Пожалуй одним лишь css не обойтись.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Однако, если у вас имеется острая необходимость реализовать задуманное исключительно на CSS, в таком случае вот вам решение. Пожалуйста, получите и распишитесь:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #222;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.5);
}

.nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 99px;
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid antiquewhite;
  z-index: 4;
}

.nav__bg__start {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: burlywood;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 0px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 0px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 0px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.2);
  z-index: 2;
}

.nav__bg {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: chocolate;
  border-bottom: 30px solid antiquewhite;
  z-index: 3;
}

.nav__bg:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3000px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Меню</li>
    <li>Меню</li>
    <li>Меню</li>
    <li>Меню</li>
    <li>Меню</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="nav__bg__start"></div>
<div class="nav__bg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Или чуть проще:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #222;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.5);
}

.nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 4;
}

.nav__bg__start {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: burlywood;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 0px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 0px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 0px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.2);
  z-index: 2;
}

.nav__bg {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: chocolate;
  z-index: 3;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3000px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Меню</li>
    <li>Меню</li>
    <li>Меню</li>
    <li>Меню</li>
    <li>Меню</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="nav__bg__start"></div>
<div class="nav__bg"></div>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант на jQuery:

```js
$(document).scroll(function(e) {
    $(window).scrollTop() > 100 ? $('.nav').addClass('nav__color') : $('.nav').removeClass('nav__color');
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

.nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: chocolate;
}

.nav__color {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav"></div>
```

`100` - насколько прокрутили (значение можете менять)

`.nav` - ваш блок

`nav__color` - класс, который добавляем/удаляем к вашему блоку

Comment: Я так понимаю при прокрутке скроллом тоже делается не через CSS, но при этом, чтобы фон немного двигался?

Comment: [EduCrown](https://colorlib.com/preview/theme/educrown/)
Вот на сайте понятнее, не знаю, правильно ли вставил ссылку, где 20K Granduanted Students

Comment: Небольшой эффект, но есть

Answer (score 1):

В общем этот эффект достигается css правилом: `background-attachment: fixed`

> Смотрим демонстрацию в сниппете (прокручиваем контент);

https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/rNVygwL - здесь этот эффект с плавной прокруткой.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 468px;
  margin: auto;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex .item {
  color: #fff;
}

.item2 {
  padding: 50px 0;
  background: url(https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/931959/6771d4ee-38b2-4b72-9089-bf68f539868b/s1200);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.item4 {
  padding: 50px 0;
  background: url(https://mensministrycatalyst.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/new-zealand-storm-900.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

p {
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item1">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Harum, cum officiis sapiente nostrum tenetur ipsa molestias? Vero minus explicabo rerum provident sed exercitationem sit minima. Illum tenetur maxime accusantium quidem!
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Harum, cum officiis sapiente nostrum tenetur ipsa molestias? Vero minus explicabo rerum provident sed exercitationem sit minima. Illum tenetur maxime accusantium quidem!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item2">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="item">20K</div>
      <div class="item">40k</div>
      <div class="item">50k</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item3">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea optio sint iusto. Et, repellat dolorem iure quas totam alias praesentium numquam dignissimos dolore placeat! Praesentium quibusdam expedita optio et totam eius, illo non tenetur alias laborum
      culpa accusantium. Omnis, magnam.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Harum, cum officiis sapiente nostrum tenetur ipsa molestias? Vero minus explicabo rerum provident sed exercitationem sit minima. Illum tenetur maxime accusantium quidem!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item4">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="item">tab</div>
      <div class="item">reverse</div>
      <div class="item">quote</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item3">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea optio sint iusto. Et, repellat dolorem iure quas totam alias praesentium numquam dignissimos dolore placeat! Praesentium quibusdam expedita optio et totam eius, illo non tenetur alias laborum
      culpa accusantium. Omnis, magnam.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Harum, cum officiis sapiente nostrum tenetur ipsa molestias? Vero minus explicabo rerum provident sed exercitationem sit minima. Illum tenetur maxime accusantium quidem!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol'  а ты открой тот сайт что он дал и посмотри  на то место где эти циферки ...увидешь что это обычный fixed....но он и в правду не пашет на мобилках но спасает то что работает fixed к блоку ..то есть можно на мобилах заменить блок с background-attachment на блок со стилем fixed

Comment: @Sevastopol' и да ...забыл ...на компах - паралакс делается на mousemove...верно ? но mouse событий нету на сотках ..это делается на deltaY и deltaX и отлавливается событие touch

Comment: @Sevastopol' если хочешь - я напишу parallax для mobile - я делал такое раньше но не часто

Comment: @Sevastopol'  http://maximumlensky.0fees.us/par.html проверь на mobile - и отпишись

Comment: @Sevastopol'  щас погоди я статичную поставлю картинку

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104958/discussion-between-maximlensky-and-sevastopol).

Comment: @Sevastopol'  проверь ссылку - я обновил содержимое